# How to serialize Flux style actions with nested payload with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I'm trying to set up custom serialization with [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for "Flux Standard Actions".

An example JSON:

```json
{
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  payload: {
    text: 'Do something.'  
  }
}
```

I've tried by declaring an interface with `@JsonSubTypes`:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AddTodoAction::class)
)
interface Action

@JsonTypeName("ADD_TODO")
data class AddTodoAction(
    val text: String
) : Action
```

And writing a custom serializer:

```kotlin
class ActionSerializer<T : Any>(clazz: KClass<T>) : StdSerializer<T>(clazz.java) {
    override fun serialize(value: T, gen: JsonGenerator?, provider: SerializerProvider?) {
        // ??
    }

    override fun serializeWithType(
        value: T?,
        gen: JsonGenerator?,
        serializers: SerializerProvider?,
        typeSer: TypeSerializer?
    ) {
        check(gen != null)
        check(serializers != null)

        if (value == null) {
            serializers.defaultSerializeNull(gen)
            return
        }

        val typeId = typeSer!!.typeId(value, JsonToken.START_OBJECT)

        typeSer.writeTypePrefix(gen, typeId)
        gen.writeFieldName("payload")
        serialize(value, gen, serializers)
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffix(gen, typeId)
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to write `serialize` function without causing infinite recursion. I'm not even sure that this is the best approach. Any suggestions? I wouldn't want to write something hackish and I don't want to have a separate class for each `payload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `gson` JsonDeserializer for basic interfaces you get out of the box 
and the JsonSerializer very easy to implement also great documented

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(TodoAction::class.java, TodoActionSerializer())
        .create()
    val jsonString = "{type: 'ADD_TODO',payload: {text: 'Do something.'}}"
    val todoAction = gson.fromJson(jsonString, TodoAction::class.java)

    print(todoAction)
}


class TodoAction(
    val type: String,
    val payload: JsonObject
)


class TodoActionSerializer : JsonSerializer<TodoAction> {
    override fun serialize(p0: TodoAction?, p1: Type?, p2: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement {
        val response = JsonObject()
        response.addProperty("type", p0!!.type)
        response.add("payload", p0.payload)
        return response
    }

}
```

Comment: Manage to solve it with gson by modifying [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java).